# How can I merge multiple xml nodes of the same type into one node?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have a fairly big xml doc that looks like:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <other>y</other>
    <notarget>x</notarget>
    <target>num1</target>
    <target>num2</target>
    <target>num3</target>
  </product>
</products>
```

But I need it to look like:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <other>y</other>
    <notarget>x</notarget>
    <target>num1,num2,num3</target>
  </product>
</products>
```

I don't have much experience with xml so I'm not even sure what technologies to use to go through the file to make these changes. There can be more than one product but this example just has one. I'm using python but I can also use a shell.

Answer (score 0):

Needing to transform from one XML to another XML is why [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) have been made.

So, this is a pure [xslt](/questions/tagged/xslt) solution using [saxon](/questions/tagged/saxon) in [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) :

#### file.xml:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <other>y</other>
    <notarget>x</notarget>
    <target>num1</target>
    <target>num2</target>
    <target>num3</target>
  </product>
</products>
```

#### xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <products>
      <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <other>y</other>
        <notarget>x</notarget>
        <target><xsl:value-of select="string-join(//target/text(), ',')" /></target>
      </product>
    </products>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### command-line:

```
$ java -cp 'saxon9he.jar' net.sf.saxon.Transform -xsl:xsl -s:file.xml '!indent=yes'
```

#### output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <other>y</other>
    <notarget>x</notarget>
    <target>num1,num2,num3</target>
  </product>
</products>
```

---

Check http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5/using-xsl.html

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like a job for [*xslt transformation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT), but here is a python-specific approach.

For every `product` find all `target` elements, remove every `target` element collecting the texts into a list. After the loop over targets, append a new `target` item to the `product`.

Implementation using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/):

```
from lxml import etree

data = """
<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <other>y</other>
    <notarget>x</notarget>
    <target>num1</target>
    <target>num2</target>
    <target>num3</target>
  </product>
</products>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(data)
for product in root.iterfind('product'):
    text = []
    for target in product.iterfind('target'):
        text.append(target.text)
        product.remove(target)

    if text:
        new_target = etree.Element('target')
        new_target.text = ','.join(text)
        product.append(new_target)

print etree.tostring(root)
```

Prints:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <other>y</other>
    <notarget>x</notarget>
    <target>num1,num2,num3</target>
  </product>
</products>
```

As you see, it works for the input you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do this on Mac OS, you need to install a [JDK from Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html), then you can install Saxon via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) from the terminal with:

```
brew install saxon
```

Then in the terminal the command I used was:

```
saxon -s:input_file.xml -xsl:transform.xsl -o:output.xml '!indent=yes'
```

Works like a charm!